# We can’t log you in because of an authentication error. For help, contact your Salesforce administrator

Tags: lightning-community, auth-provider

We are trying to implement custom auth provider to facilitate users from a different domain can log into Salesforce with domain credentials.

Flow:-

```
1.User will login to web application with domain credentials
2.To access Community user will click on Community url (Community Single Sign-On Initialization URL)
3.SSO link will redirect to domain authorization endpoint with code and state
4.Authorization link will redirect to Community Callback URL with access token 
5.Custom Authprovider callback handler will use token to get user details
6.Reghandler will query users based on received response
```

I tried to implement custom auth with java web application.I referenced Salesforce documentation for [Create a Custom External Authentication Provider](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_plugin_custom.htm&type=5)

AuthProvider code:

```
   global PageReference initiate(Map<string,string> authProviderConfiguration, String stateToPropagate) {
   System.debug('authProviderConfiguration'+authProviderConfiguration);
   authUrl = authProviderConfiguration.get('Auth_URL__c');
   System.debug('authUrl'+ authUrl);
   key = authProviderConfiguration.get('key__c');
   System.debug('key'+ key);
   redirectUrl = authProviderConfiguration.get('redirectUrl__c');
   System.debug('redirectUrl'+ redirectUrl);
   String url = authUrl + '?client_id='+ key +'&response_type=code&redirect_uri='+ redirectUrl + '&state=' + stateToPropagate ;
   System.debug('Routing to My Site with details'+ url);
   return new PageReference(url);
```

---

Handler code:

```
global Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse handleCallback(Map<string,string> authProviderConfiguration, Auth.AuthProviderCallbackState state ) {
   System.debug('Call back handler' + state);
     System.debug('Call back handler' + state.queryParameters);
   key = authProviderConfiguration.get('key__c');
   secret = authProviderConfiguration.get('secret__c');
   accessTokenUrl = authProviderConfiguration.get('Access_Token_Url__c');
   redirectURL = authProviderConfiguration.get('redirectUrl__c');

   Map<String,String> queryParams = state.queryParameters;
   String code = queryParams.get('code');
   String sfdcState = queryParams.get('state');
   String myUser_Id = queryParams.get('myUser_Id');

   Http http = new Http();
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   String url = accessTokenUrl;
   req.setEndpoint(url);
   req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   req.setMethod('POST');
     String body ='client_id=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(key,'UTF-8') + '&client_secret=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(secret,'UTF-8') + '&redirect_uri=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(redirectURL,'UTF-8') + '&code=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(code,'UTF-8') + '&myUser_Id='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(myUser_Id,'UTF-8');

   req.setBody(body);
   HTTPResponse res = new HTTPResponse();
   try{
    res = http.send(req);
   }catch(System.CalloutException e){System.debug('Callout error:'+ e);
   System.debug(res.toString());}
   String responseBody = res.getBody();
   Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody);
   String token = (String)responseMap.get('access_token');
   System.debug('Call back handler'+ token +'<<Token'+'state>>'+sfdcState);
   return new Auth.AuthProviderTokenResponse('Incapsula', token, null, sfdcState);
}
```

I am using auto generated Reghandler:

```
global class AutocreatedRegHandler1432826053915 implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{
global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
    User u = [SELECT ID FROM User Where email = : data.username];
    return u;
}
global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){

}
```

}

Tested from Community login page using Custom auth:
Result:I can login to web application and after successful login re-directing to Community callback url. I am not sure why Community callback is redirecting to "https://test.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/sso/ui/AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=B

Tested from web application:
After successful login I am getting 503 Service Unavailable on Community callback url

Auth Provider:
[image]

Community links (My domain is deployed for all users):
[image]

Comment: Hi, the level of information provided here is not sufficient to be able to provide any resolution. Please take a moment to visit [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/237215/edit). You are missing here key information as how is your SSO setup, what is the IdP, how is the callback URL configured, etc.

Comment: Hi Jayant I have added all information

Comment: Have you updated the callback URL on your external authentication provider that you are using?

Comment: yes I have updated the callback on Identity provider.

Comment: Working Flow:-1. Customer SSO link is redirecting to identity provider login link 2.After successful login identity provider is redirecting to Community Callback url with State and Code.3.On community callback url I am getting authentication error and callback handler is not executing

Comment: @Abhi, did you ever figure out your error?  I am getting the same error.  Thank you!

Comment: ^ I found my error.  I was constructing bad callback URL.  I forgot the `?` to start my query parameters

Comment: @ScottPelak why did you need to construct a callback URL? Salesforce will generate it for u as in OP's screenshot above